# Disable button and show "Please wait.." text on button while form post

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form which posts data to another website. What I want to do is to disable the button and show *"Please wait..."* text in it. till it submits the form to some URL.

I tried doing that through JavaScript `onclick` function where the `onclick` function is working fine, but the form is not posting.

Comment: Please provide your code @AfZaal

Comment: If you want to get help you will need to post an excerpt of the JavaScript code you have tried and as a bare minimum the HTML code from the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use onSubmit handler on form
2. when API is called change style and text of your button
3. when you get response revert button styles and text

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is after clicking on the button you can pass an ajax request to the php page with the data and submit it to the database from there and parallely you can change the button after the success function returns true revert back the button